# Why is the JSON returning a null/blank result when parsed as a JObject? C#

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am having some trouble gathering JSON from a url. I read the JSON successfully as a string async but when i try to parse to as a JObject it returns null/blank result.

The JSON looks like this:

```
[{"name":"Name","desc":"Desc","id":1}, {"name":"Name","desc":"Desc","id":2}]
```

And here is the code:

```
    static public async Task<JObject> getData()
    {
            var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient();
            var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync("url");
            var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(resultString); //returns the json as a string

            var jsonResult = JObject.Parse(resultString);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(jsonResult); //returns null/blank result
            return jsonResult;
    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Your data looks like an array. Try parsing as JArray instead of JObject

Comment: The root container is a JSON array not a JSON object.  Use `JArray.Parse()`, or `JToken.Parse()` if you don't know the JSON contents in advance.

Comment: Thanks guys! Works now :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var jsonResult = JArray.Parse(resultString);
```